# Get Bit values from Byte Array

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a byte array from which I need to read specific bits and convert to int (see the byte array structure below). Even though the bits information I want to read is in 3 bytes, I tried reading 4 bytes (6-9) as integer and then read the bits from that integer value with bits or bitsValue method but somehow I am not able to see the right values from the bit manipulation. And with my expertise in bits I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. 
Can someone please suggest I am doing it correctly and why its not working. Thanks in Advance!!

Byte array is in Little Endian format.

0th byte - Some Value
1st Byte - Some Value
2nd - 5th Byte - Some Value
6th - 9th Byte - first 18 bits represent some value
               - Next 5 bits represent some value
               - Next 1 bit represent some value
               - Last 8 bits represent some value

```
 public class Test {

  public static void main(String... dataProvider) {
    String s = "46 00 ef 30 e9 08 cc a5 03 43";
    byte[] bytes = new byte[s.length()];
    bytes = hexStringToByteArray(s);

    int bytePointer = 0;
    int msgType = getIntFromSingleByte(bytes[bytePointer]); // 0th byte
    int version = getIntFromSingleByte(bytes[++bytePointer]); // 1st byte
    int tickInMS = getIntValue(bytes, ++bytePointer); // 2nd-5th bytes

    bytePointer = bytePointer + 4;
    int headr = getIntValue(bytes, bytePointer); // 6th-9th bytes
    int utcTime = bits(headr, 0, 18); // 6th-9th bytes - 18 bits
    int reserved = bits(headr, 18, 5); // 6th-9th bytes- 5 bits
    int reportOrEvent = bits(headr, 23, 1); // 6th-9th bytes - 1 bits
    int reportId = bitsValue(headr, 24, 32); // 6th-9th- 8 bits

  }



    public static int getIntFromSingleByte(byte data) {
        return (data & 0xFF);
      }

      public static int getIntValue(byte[] bytes, int startPosition) {
        byte[] dest = new byte[4];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, startPosition, dest, 0, dest.length);
        return toInt(dest);
      }

      // took from Stack overflow
      static int bits(int n, int offset, int length) {
        // shift the bits rightward, so that the desired chunk is at the right end
        n = n >> (31 - offset - length);
        // prepare a mask where only the rightmost `length` bits are 1's
        int mask = ~(-1 << length);
        // zero out all bits but the right chunk
        return n & mask;
      }

      public static int bitsValue(int intNum, int startBitPos, int endBitPos) {
        // parameters checking ignored for now
        int tempValue = intNum << endBitPos;
        return tempValue >> (startBitPos + endBitPos);
      }

      public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(final String s) {
        String[] splits = s.split(" ");
        final byte[] data = new byte[splits.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
          char first = splits[i].length() < 2 ? '0' : splits[i].charAt(0);
          char second = splits[i].length() < 2 ? splits[i].charAt(0) : splits[i].charAt(1);
          data[i] = (byte) ((Character.digit(first, 16) << 4) + Character.digit(second, 16));
        }
    return data;
  }

  public static int toInt(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null || data.length != 4)
      return 0x0;

    return (int) ((0xff & data[0]) << 24 | (0xff & data[1]) << 16 | (0xff & data[2]) << 8
        | (0xff & data[3]) << 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping your input data in a `ByteBuffer` will simplify parsing and allow you to adjust endianness as necessary.

Your `bits` method is wrong. The constant 31 should be 32. Also, the method uses MSB 0 bit numbering, which is odd for little-endian data. You should confirm that your input is documented as using this bit numbering scheme.

Your `bitsValue` method is wrong too. May as well just use `bits` after fixing it.

This code is simpler and extracts the bit fields correctly:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String s = "46 0 79 37 a8 3 9f 37 1 43 eb 7a f 3 3 fe c4 1 c5 4 c5 5e";
    byte[] input = hexStringToByteArray(s);

    // Wrap the input in a ByteBuffer for parsing. Adjust endianness if necessary.
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(input).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    int msgType = buffer.get() & 0xff;
    int version = buffer.get() & 0xff;
    int tickInMS = buffer.getInt();
    int header = buffer.getInt();

    int utcTime = bits(header, 0, 18);          // 6th-9th bytes - 18 bits
    int reserved = bits(header, 18, 5);         // 6th-9th bytes - 5 bits
    int reportOrEvent = bits(header, 23, 1);    // 6th-9th bytes - 1 bit
    int reportId = bits(header, 24, 8);         // 6th-9th bytes - 8 bits

    System.out.printf("utc: %d, report? %d, id: %d\n", utcTime, reportOrEvent, reportId);
}

/**
 * Extract a bit field from an int. Bit numbering is MSB 0.
 */
public static int bits(int n, int offset, int length) {
    return n >> (32 - offset - length) & ~(-1 << length);
}
```

Comment: this is sample I was using "46 0 79 37 a8 3 9f 37 1 43 eb 7a f 3 3 fe c4 1 c5 4 c5 5e" 11 bit (eb) should be 235 but when I am passing it through logic its giving me -21

Comment: But you're not reading byte 11 in your example (it stops at 10).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of error prone bit mangeling you should rather use the *binary string representation* of the numbers and do your "bit picking" as string operations:

```
String s = "46 00 ef 30 e9 08 cc a5 03 43";
String[] hexNumbers = s.split(" ");
for(String hexNumber : hexNumbers) {
  String binaryNumber = String.format("%8s", new BigInteger(hexNumber,16).toString(2)).replace(' ','0');
  System.out.print(String.format("value in hex : %s, value in binary: %s",  hexNumber,binaryNumber));
}
```

Comment: hex number were running the test cases. in production system I need to work with actual bytes. I don't want to add an additional step of converting hex and doing on manipulation in them. Even in that case I am not sure If I understand how can I read 18/5/1 bites from 3 hex numbers (3 bytes)

Comment: Did you test that? %s with flag 0 throws for me on Oracle Java 8 and earlier, and the javadoc for `Formatter` agrees 0 doesn't work on category 'general' which 's' is. (This differs from C and C++ where 0 flag can be applied to any conversion.)